# How to make autocomplete unsplash search bar clone

Tags: reactjs, api, autocomplete, searchbar

I want to create a clone of Unsplash search bar: https://unsplash.com/
When user start typing it displays suggestions under search bar. I want to implement this functionality.

I use React.

I didn't find options for autocompletion in API: https://unsplash.com/developers

I can use the same request that website uses: https://unsplash.com/nautocomplete/

The problem is that it has CORS protection, so I can't access it normally like other API.
I can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a proxy but it has limited request and is far from ideal solution.
e.g: `await axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url)`

Is there another way to get this autocomplete information? Maybe I can do it with original API?
Or maybe there is a good no proxy fix for CORS?